# Passing math-like string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble on passing time interval to javascript. The time interval is formatted using minus sign (Eg. 10-11 means from 10 to 11 AM/PM doesn't matter).

In markup I have something like this.

```
<? $mytime = '10-11';?>

<a href="" onclick="checkTime($mytime)"></a>
```

In Javascript I have this

```
function checkTime(mytime) {
    console.log(mytime);
}
```

Console window show -1. i need to have the same string I passed. What should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass value like this

```
<a href="#" onclick="checkTime('$mytime')"></a>
```

instad of

```
<a href="" onclick="checkTime($mytime)"></a>
```

You are passing `10-11`. which without '' javascript consider this as number.

This make 10-11=-1

Something like this

```
function v(i){console.log(typeof i);}
v(10-11) // number
v("10-11") // string
```

Comment: Explaining why you  surround the variable with single quotes will be more helpful

Comment: Thank you so much , It worked and I understood how it works now. @Anik Islam Abhi

Comment: Now this explains a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
<a href="" onclick="checkTime('<? echo $mytime ?>')"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are printing your php string directly in the onlick function, this will output something like this:

```
 <a href="" onclick="checkTime(10-11)"></a>
```

You can easily see how this will not work. That's why you need to put the single inverted commas before printing your php var, so that it appears as a string in js: onlick="checkTime('10-11')"